# ReSharper 2016.1 don't apply file layout on c# file

Tags: c#, resharper

Since update on ReSharper 2016.1 CodeCleanup with "Apply file layout" don't works.
Anybody have same problems?

Can I validate file layout xaml?

Regards

Steffen